# Sheaf cohomology of the complement of a schubert variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, grassmannians, flag-varieties, vanishing

Let $k$ be a field, $d,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and denote by $Gr(d,n)$ the Grassmannian, which parameterizes the $d$-dimensional linear subspaces of $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space, considered as a projective variety (resp. scheme).

Define $W_{(d,n)}:=\{w \in S_{n-1} \mid w(1) < w(2) < \ldots < w(d), w(d+1) < \ldots < w(n) \}$ and for $w \in W_{d,n}$ let $X(w) \subset Gr(d,n)$ be the corresponding Schubert variety.

For $d=1$, $Gr(1,n)=\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$ and we can index the elements of $W_{(d,n)}$ by $I=\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $w_j(1)=j$. Then $X(w_j)=\mathbb{P}^{j}_k$ and by considering the Čech complex for the (partial) standard covering of the projective space it follows that $H^i(\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k-X(w_j),\mathcal{O})=0$ for $i\geq$ codim$(X(w_j))=n-1-j$

Does this also hold for general $d$, i.e. is $H^i(Gr(d,n)-X(w),\mathcal{O})=0$ for $d\geq 1$, $w \in W_{d,n}$ and $i \geq$ codim$(X(w))$?

ADDENDUM: I found recently the paper "Ample subvarieties and q-ample divisors" by Ottem, from which immediately follows that the answer above would be true for the Schubert varieties $X(w)$ which are ample in the sense of Ottem. For example for d=1 all Schubert varieties are ample. So it is known which $X(w)$ have this property or what a good way would be to tackle this problem?